# Not booting from USB Drive

Tags: boot

I downloaded 12.04 of ubuntu, and y copied the 718 mb file to my usb Kingston Drive (which is 2gb total) and i tried booting it from setup and it can't! I click booting from USB kingston and it boots Windows normally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the file to the USB is not enough - you need to use a program called [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB drive

[image]

(That is, if you're on Windows or MacOSX)

If you run Ubuntu, use Startup Disk Creator which is installed by default:

[image]

See [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you might want to run "startup disk creator" or burn the image to your USB pen drive.

keep in mind that a simple copy of the iso file you've just downloaded wont work at all.