# Ubuntu is not booting from my pen drive

Tags: boot, usb-drive

I have a 4GB pendrive. I have installed ubuntu 14.04 into it. But, ubuntu is not booting from it. Whenever I try to boot from it, only a black screen is up. May be the bootloader is keep on searching for a valid boot source within my pendrive which does not exist at all. Please help me resolve this problem.

I followed these steps to install ubuntu into my pendrive:

- I created an extended-partition covering all the 4GB.
- I created two primary partitions within it.

  - partition one - ext4 filesystem - 3.5 GB
  - partition two - ext2 filesystem - rest of the total memory
- I used a liveUSB to install ubuntu into my pendrive
- I chose my partition one - ext4 fs for ubuntu installation with the mount point as **/**
- I chose my partition two - ext2 fs as a swap area for the ubuntu to be installed
- I then hit *Install Now* which did the installation, similar to an installation in HDD

Have I done anything wrong? Do I need to do more things? Help me use ubuntu from my pendrive. Thanks in advance.

---

**Update:** I tried for solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253366/ubuntu-not-booting-from-usb) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131174/not-booting-from-usb-drive). Nothing helped. They were just stuffs related to liveUSB creation which is not my case.

Comment: You could also start with a liveUSB. Not much can go wrong then. After bootup you can still choose for a fresh Ubuntu install on your harddrive. Tha'ts the way i did yesterday

Comment: My case is not creating a liveUSB. I need to install it in my pendrive. I wish to carry it wherever I go.

Comment: How do I be sure of that MBR stuff? Can you please brief about what is MBR?

Comment: How do I check whether the bootloader is installed into the MBR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The 4GB USB drive is too small for a full install of Ubuntu 14.04**

The installer should have refused to install Ubuntu in a 3.5 GB partition. [A full install requires about 5GB `/` partition.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) So you will need at least an 8 GB USB drive. I recommend a 16 or 32 GB drive if you intend to install many programs and store large personal files.

One thing to remember when you install Ubuntu on an USB drive, from a Live USB is to make sure you choose the correct destination drive for installation as well as the bootloader location.

Your drives are denoted by `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` etc. Say `/dev/sdc` is the correct USB drive (check by size). Then during install make sure you choose `/dev/sdc` for bootloader location. Don't choose partitions inside such as `/dev/sdc1`. Choosing the whole drive (rather than a partition in it) will install the bootloader in the MBR of that USB drive.

There are other ways of doing a full install in an USB, such as using a virtual machine. See [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) for more details.

Hope this helps